# Nested for loop of a definition in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm trying to deploy some terraform that creates multiple VM's then defines some load balancer rules but I'm struggling with getting the string format right for the 2nd for_each

This part

```
for_each = {for server in local.instances: server.instance_name =>  server}
```

in the aws_instance blocks works beautifully but I need to then iterate though the fwd_rules for each VM in the serverconfig. I'm in control of the format in "configuration" so if it's just a case of getting the right string format to be able to do it then that's great.

What should I set here? I've tried lots of different options, toset, tolist, tomap, playing with the string format of fwd_rules with braces, square brackets etc. and I just can't get it right.

```
dynamic "path_pattern" {
      for_each = toset(each.value.fwd_rules)
```

Terraform Code: (simplified)

```
configuration = [
  {
    "application_name" : "myapp",
    "fwd_rules" : "{'/foo/*','/bar/*'}"
  },
  {
    "application_name" : "myapp2",
    "fwd_rules" : "{'/foo2/*','/bar2/*'}"
  }]

locals {
  serverconfig = [
    for srv in var.configuration : [
      for i in range(1, srv.no_of_instances+1) : {
        instance_name = "${srv.application_name}"
        fwd_rules = "${srv.fwd_rules}"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

locals {
  instances = flatten(local.serverconfig)
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-instance" {

    for_each = {for server in local.instances: server.instance_name =>  server}
    instance_name               = each.value.instance_name
    tags = {
      Name = "${each.value.instance_name}"
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "myrule" {
  for_each = {for server in local.instances: server.instance_name =>  server}

  condition {
    dynamic "path_pattern" {
      for_each = toset(each.value.fwd_rules) 
      content {
        values = [path_pattern.value]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the following

```
configuration = [
  {
    "application_name" : "myapp",
    "fwd_rules" : "'/foo/*','/bar/*'"
  },
  {
    "application_name" : "myapp2",
    "fwd_rules" : "'/foo2/*','/bar2/*'"
  }]

locals {
  serverconfig = [
    for srv in var.configuration : [
      for i in range(1, srv.no_of_instances+1) : {
        instance_name = "${srv.application_name}"
        fwd_rules = split(",", srv.fwd_rules)
      }
    ]
  ]
}

locals {
  instances = flatten(local.serverconfig)
}

resource "aws_instance" "my-instance" {

    for_each = {for server in local.instances: server.instance_name =>  server}
    instance_name               = each.value.instance_name
    tags = {
      Name = "${each.value.instance_name}"
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "myrule" {
  for_each = {for server in local.instances: server.instance_name =>  server}

  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = each.value.fwd_rules 
    }
  }
}
```

The main thing that unlocked it was the function

```
        fwd_rules = split(",", srv.fwd_rules)
```